# Show ActionMode over ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode, android-cab

I have a list activity in which the user can do open action modes `A` and `B`. The user can also open action mode `A` then `B` on top of it.

The problem is that when action mode `A` is shown and action mode B is shown on top of it, `A` gets closed automatically when `B` is shown. The user can't navigate back from `B` to `A`.

I thought I could take note of action mode `A` visibility when action mode `B` is opened then restore it when action mode `B` is closed, but that doesn't work. It seems that it's not possible to immediately show another action mode after closing one. However this issue only happens if the action mode A is closed with the back arrow. When closed by code (`ActionMode.finish()`), action mode `B` can be shown, but the closing animation doesn't make it look like user is navigating back from `B` to `A`. So this solution is out of question.

So is there a way to open an action mode on top of another, or at least replace the menu layout of an action mode programatically then change it back?

Action mode `A` is actually the search action mode, from which the user can select results which opens action mode `B` if that can help to understand.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: I don't think that would help, the question is really about finding a way to show two actionmodes, the solution I found just won't do.

Comment: Could you post some screenshot of your requirement?

Comment: I can't, I didn't manage to do it and never saw it on any app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I reached desired behavior through postDelayed() from onDestroyActionMode of action mode B.
This is not very elegant solution, but it works.

My code snippet:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, p2, p3 ->
            startActionModeA()
            true
        }
    }

    var actionModeA: ActionMode? = null

    val actionModeCallbackA = object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, p1: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            Log.wtf("ACTION MODE", "onActionItemClicked")
            actionModeB = startActionMode(actionModeCallbackB)
            return true
        }

        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            Log.wtf("ACTION MODE", "onCreateActionMode")
            val inflater = mode?.getMenuInflater()
            inflater?.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(p0: ActionMode?, p1: Menu?): Boolean {
            Log.wtf("ACTION MODE", "onPrepareActionMode")
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(p0: ActionMode?) {
            Log.wtf("ACTION MODE", "onDestroyActionMode")
            actionModeA = null
        }


    }
    var actionModeB: ActionMode? = null

    val actionModeCallbackB = object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, p1: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            Log.wtf("ACTION MODE 2", "onActionItemClicked")
            return true
        }

        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            Log.wtf("ACTION MODE 2", "onCreateActionMode")
            val inflater = mode?.getMenuInflater()
            inflater?.inflate(R.menu.context_menu2, menu)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(p0: ActionMode?, p1: Menu?): Boolean {
            Log.wtf("ACTION MODE 2", "onPrepareActionMode")
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
            Log.wtf("ACTION MODE 2", "onDestroyActionMode")
            actionModeB = null
            listView.postDelayed({
                startActionModeA()
            }, 100)
        }
    }

    private fun startActionModeA() {
        actionModeA = startActionMode(actionModeCallbackA)
    }
```

Comment: It works perfectly thanks! Definitively not elegant code but in the app it looks perfect.